# How are the estimators of the coefficients?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

We have the model $$\tilde{Y}=50+0.3X_2+2.5X_3$$ where $Y$ are the food costs in euro, $X_2$ is the income in euro and $X_3$ is the number of children.

If we consider the income in thousands euros then how are the estimators of the coefficients?

Normally we get the estimators $\tilde{\beta}_1, \tilde{\beta}_2, \tilde{\beta}_3$ as the coefficients from above (constant term, coefficient of $X_2$, coefficient of $X_3$ respectively)

But using the information that the income is considered in thousands euros, do we have to multiply/divide the coefficient of $X_2$ by $1000$ ?

Comment: If the incomes are expressed in thousand Euros, the coefficients will be in Euros, Euros per thousand Euros and Euros per children respectively.

Comment: So $0.3$ is Euros per thousand Euros, that means that $\tilde{\beta}_2=\frac{0.3}{1000}$ ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: No, $\bar\beta_2$ is $0.3$.

Comment: So we have $\tilde{\beta}_1=50$, $\tilde{\beta}_2=\frac{0.3}{1000}=0.0003$, $\tilde{\beta}_3=2.5$ ?@YvesDaoust

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: I got stuck right now. $Y$ is in euro and $X_2$ is in thousands euros, so to get the same do we not have to multiply or divide by $1000$ ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: No, $\bar\beta_2=0.3$, as written. Whatever the units.

Comment: So do we have $\tilde{\beta}_1=50, \tilde{\beta}_2=0.3, \tilde{\beta}_3=2.5$ ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Unless the last term is per microchildren ?

Comment: What do you mean ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Nothing, just kidding.

Comment: I am just wondering because I looked now at the possible answers, and this one is not there. The possible answers for $\tilde{\beta}_1$ are $(a) 0.05 , \ \ (b) 50  \ \ (c) 5000$ and the possible answers for $\tilde{\beta}_2$ are $(a) 0.0003, \ \ (b) 300$ @YvesDaoust

Comment: Then you probably don't show the whole question.

Comment: No, that it the question... Maybe there is a typo? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Then I disagree with the author.